# Java regex, separate degree & coeff of polynomial

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble understanding how regex syntax works. I try to use it to read from a String the coefficients and degrees of a polynomial. I saw similar questions, but it wasn't clear enough for me. Found how to extract coefficients but when I tried to do the same for the degree I found out it beats me.
For an input like: 2x^3+3x^2

```
        //for coeff
        String[] coef = str.split("x\\^\\d+\\+?");
        for (String part : coef)
        {
            System.out.println(part);
         }

        //for degree
        String[] degree = str.split("+\\+?\\d");
        for (String part : degree)
        {
            System.out.println(part);
         }
```

Already consulted [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html).

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: 2 3 for coef. 3 2 for degree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using 2 different regex and doing 2 split operations I suggest using a match with a single regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(-?\\b\\d+)[xX]\\^(-?\\d+\\b)" );
```

You can then use `Matcher.find()` to get both `coef` (matched group 1) and degree (matched group 2).

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zH8mE4/4)

---

**Code:**

```
String input = "2x^3-3x^-2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(-?\\b\\d+)[xX]\\^(-?\\d+\\b)" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Coef: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Degree: " + m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Sure I can tweak it. Can degrees also be negative?

Comment: I had it working for degrees, but having trouble with coefficients for example: `2x^3-3x^-2`  was treating the 2nd coef as -3 instead of just 3

Comment: The coefficient there should be -3?

Comment: ok I updated the answer and it should work (see all 3 examples in my demo)

Comment: I asked one question in the answer above, think you can check it ? :D

Comment: @LorenaSfăt: I will again suggest not to use `split` for this as you may get some unwanted characters in your matched array and that will cause this `NumberFormatException`. Regex shown in my answer will guarantee to match only numbers.

Comment: But I'm a newbie and I've never used Pattern or Matcher before :D

Comment: One can always learn and adapt. I will add code in my answer in a min

Answer (score 2):

```
String monomPattern = "((-?\\d+(?=x))?(-?[xX])(\\^(-?\\d+))?)|((-?)[xX])|(-?\\d+)";
```

This should work if you don't have any white spaces. If you have, simply 
call the replaceAll("\s+","") method for strings. (this method do not change the original String, so you have to assign it to itself)

```
e.g. textField = textField.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

ims

Answer (score 1):

Just split your input according to the below regex for getting degree values.

```
String s[] = str.split("\\+?\\d+x\\^");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lS8aQ1/2)

Comment: Yes it works, thank you. I have another question. Now I try to convert them from String to int like this `int d=Integer.parseInt(degree[i]);` but it gives me NumberFormatException, and I can't figure how to avoid it.

Comment: try `int d=Integer.parseInt(degree[i].trim());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this REGEX:

```
  /*GROUP 1 = sign (optional for positive numbers) -> -3x; (+3x, 3x)
    GROUP 2 = digit (optional if it's -1 or 1) -> (-1x, -x); (1x, x)
    GROUP 3 = term with x in its structure -> 3x, -5x^2
    GROUP 4 = exponent structure (^exponent) (optional if it's 1) -> (4x^1, 4x); 4x^-1; 2x^3
    The REGEX supports integer and real values: 4.5, 4., 0.25, .25 etc.
    The REGEX does not support fractions: 3/4, 6/4 (use the real value: 0.75, 1.25)
     */
    String monomialPattern = "([-+]?)(\\d*\\.?\\d*)?([xX](\\^-?\\d*\\.?\\d*)?)?"

    Polynomial parsedPolynomial = new Polynomial();

    // double backslash stands for \s which represents a white space
    // + means that all the white spaces from the String will be replaced with ""
    input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

    // Converts the REGEX string into a valid pattern
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(monomialPattern);

    // Creates an object which will test the pattern against the input
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
```

You can exercise regular expressions here: [REGEXR](https://regexr.com/)